# Using a SurfaceView in a RecyclerView

Tags: android, scroll, video-streaming, android-mediaplayer, surfaceview

I am using a list to display videos to choose from and the header of the list has a `SurfaceView` in which I connect the `MediaPlayer` using `setDisplay()` to show the clip.
The problem is, when I scroll down. The `SurfaceHolder` is destroyed, which is ok I guess, to save resources. Once I scroll up again, the `surfaceCreated` method is called in which I use `setDisplay()` again. It works showing the video again, but it seems as it skips back a second or so, so it sounds laggy.

how can I fix this?

Comment: Texture view should work a bit better. But remember that a TextureView will consume more phone resource (memory especially). Per Androids documentation a TextureView instance has uses about ~4MB more than a SurfaceView

Comment: Is that used in the YouTube app?

Comment: tried to use TextureView, now it does not lag when I scroll the video away but it dows lag when I scroll back to the video

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned on this link: https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/faqs.html#how-do-i-get-smooth-animationscrolling-of-video :

> SurfaceView rendering wasn’t properly synchronized with view animations until Android N. On earlier releases this could result in unwanted effects when a SurfaceView was placed into scrolling container, or when it was subjected to animation. Such effects included the SurfaceView’s contents appearing to lag slightly behind where it should be displayed, and the view turning black when subjected to animation.
>
> To achieve smooth animation or scrolling of video prior to Android N, it’s therefore necessary to use TextureView rather than SurfaceView. If smooth animation or scrolling is not required then SurfaceView should be preferred (see [Should I use SurfaceView or TextureView](https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/faqs.html#should-i-use-surfaceview-or-textureview)?).